# Specific keys occasionally not working on a bluetooth Microsoft keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Windows bluetooth keyboard where a couple of keys (m and backspace) consistently stop working (for example now it's working but half an hour ago it wasn't). The device manager shows the keyboard is working fine. I tried it on another machine and same result so I'm assuming it's a hardware error. Event Manager looks pretty clean, drivers are saying no issues. Does anyone have some tips to debug this further?

Thanks

Comment: "I tried it on another machine and same result so I'm assuming it's a hardware error"  <-- A reasonable assumption. Did you put fresh batteries in the Keyboard?

Comment: @John thanks for your comment. Yes I have tried putting fresh batteries in which didn't improve things. My reason for thinking it *might* be software is the transience of it.

Comment: That means the keyboard is defective and needs to be replaced.